# Unknown CMake command "zephyr_library"

Tags: zephyr-rtos

i am trying to add a out of tree driver to the sample blinky project .
I can build blinky project successfully , so i dont think i have any problem with my setup.
this is what i've done ;
[my project file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK07W.png)

the bottom right violet boxes are the 2 different test cases that i tested.

When i try to build my project i got this error ;

```
-- west build: generating a build system
CMake Error at
c:\Users\mehmetcan.balci\Desktop\test\blinky\build\drivers\adxl362Ext\CMakeLists.txt:2 (zephyr_library):
      Unknown CMake command "zephyr_library".
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I have used image file to demonstrate my files, because there are too many kconfig and cmakelist.txt files...

How can i solve this issue ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`zephyr_library` is a function defined in one of the cmake zephyr modules: `extensions.cmake`.

Cmake does not found this module in its `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.
It is typically set by `find_package`.